# ¿Como hacer que mi APK sea compatible con cualquier dispositivo?

Tags: android, app, apk

Estoy haciendo una APP con android studio.
La he acabado le he hecho Build correcto pero he intentado instalarla en un "Huawei P8 Lite" y me dice que no es compatible con el dispositivo.

¿Que parte del código es la que la hace incompatible?

Este es el archivo "AndroidManifest.xml"

`

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
    android:name="com.mp3player.searchonline.App" >
    <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mp3player.searchonline.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mp3player.searchonline.PlayerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyDialogTheme" >
        </activity>
</application>
```

`

Comment: Que versión de Android es tu Huawei P8Lite?

Comment: Es un Android 6.0

Comment: hola y disculpa que hasta ahora te conteste. Lo que pasa es que en el manifest agregaste esto: `<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />` la versión mínima es la 15 = Android 4.0.4 y la máxima o target es la 22 = Android 5.1
Este es el posible dilema por el que no pudiste instalar en el P8Lite. Igualmente si es en Android Studio, si estos valores estan declarados en el archivo build.gradle (Module:app) son los que estan en este no en el manifest.

Comment: Revisa [esta dirección](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html?hl=es-419) con calma, ahí te explica lo que es el nivel del API y pues creo que te orientará a futuro mejor. Saludos